# How to return content of Outline window?

Tags: ide

I'm running Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, Version: Kepler Service Release 2 (4.3.2) with Force.com IDE Version: Summer '14 (31.0.0).

Some time ago content stopped displaying in Outline window. Is it only me?

How to return content of Outline window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not only you that has this problem - see this [bug list](https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/issues?q=outline). The problem is with the new Apex parser which crashed on some fairly common Apex constructs.

Those bugs are marked as fixed, but AFAIK there hasn't been a release with those fixes in it. If you are adventurous, you could try out the [beta version](https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/wiki/Downloading-the-Beta-Version-of-the-Force.com-IDE), though I'm not sure if that is just a nightly build (and so could have worse defects) or is some kind of controlled quality version.